# Plugin.LocalNotification not working in release mode on Android

Tags: android, maui, release, .net-7.0

I've added Plugin.LocalNotification to my .NET 7 MAUI project.

It work perfectly on iOS (tested in iOS 17), but on Android it only works on API <=33 in debug mode.

On API 34 in debug and <=33 in release, nothing happens and I get the following application output: "SendNotification: Notification 100 has no NotifyTime".

On API 34 in release mode the application crashes when triggering a notification. Here's a snippet from my code for creating a notification:

```
     var notification = new NotificationRequest
        {
            NotificationId = 100,
            Title = "Test",
            Description = "Test Description",
            ReturningData = "Dummy data",
            Schedule = { NotifyTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10) }
        };
```